# React: Trigger button click from array map by another child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a parent component `App` and it has a child `Content` & `Trigger`. From the `Content` component, I have an array of content with **radio button** and a hidden **button**. The `Trigger` component has only one **button**.

My question is, how can I trigger a button click inside the `Content` component from the `Trigger` component depending on what the user selected on the `Content` component.

If my explanation is hard to understand, maybe my code does. Thank you.

CodeSandbox Sample
https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-kirch-g2r10?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import Content from "./Content";
import Trigger from "./Trigger";
import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.PureComponent {
  state = {
    selectedOption: ""
  };

  onRadioButtonChange = name => {
    this.setState({
      selectedOption: name
    });
  };

  onClickTriggerButton = e => {
    const { selectedOption } = this.state;
    e.preventDefault();
    switch (selectedOption) {
      case "opt1":
        console.log("trigger click on option 1");
        break;
      case "opt2":
        console.log("trigger click on option 2");
        break;
      case "opt3":
        console.log("trigger click on option 3");
        break;
      default:
        console.log("Select a method...");
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Content onRadioButtonChange={this.onRadioButtonChange} />
        <Trigger onClickTriggerButton={this.onClickTriggerButton} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Content.js

```
import React from "react";

class Content extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    const { onRadioButtonChange } = this.props;

    const tabs = [
      {
        name: "option_1_name",
        content: (
          <div className="Option-Method">
            <input
              type="radio"
              name="group"
              onChange={() => onRadioButtonChange("opt1")}
            />
            Option Medthod 1 - Randon text...
            <button
              hidden
              onClick={() => console.log("option 1 button clicked!")}
            />
          </div>
        )
      },
      {
        name: "option_2_name",
        content: (
          <div className="Option-Method">
            <input
              type="radio"
              name="group"
              onChange={() => onRadioButtonChange("opt2")}
            />
            Option Medthod 2 - Randon text...
            <button
              hidden
              onClick={() => console.log("option 2 button clicked!")}
            />
          </div>
        )
      },
      {
        name: "option_3_name",
        content: (
          <div className="Option-Method">
            <input
              type="radio"
              name="group"
              onChange={() => onRadioButtonChange("opt3")}
            />
            Option Medthod 3 - Randon text...
            <button
              hidden
              onClick={() => console.log("option 3 button clicked!")}
            />
          </div>
        )
      }
    ];

    return (
      <form className="Content">
        <fieldset id="group">
          {tabs.map((attribute, index) => {
            const key = `${attribute.name}-${index}`;
            return (
              <div key={key} className="Option">
                {attribute.content}
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default Content;
```

Trigger.js

```
import React from "react";

class Trigger extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    const { onClickTriggerButton } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className="Trigger">
        <button onClick={onClickTriggerButton}>Trigger Selected Option</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Trigger;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass ref to the Content component and for each hidden button check for the selectedOption if that matches set ref for that hidden button. Also wrap the Content component in React.forwardRef.

```
<button
   hidden
   ref={"opt1" === selectedOption ? ref : null}
   onClick={() => console.log("option 1 button clicked!")}
/>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-hodgkin-jm84w?file=/src/Content.js:507-671

Comment: Is there a way by using state, ref, or by passing a handler instead of checking it from a DOM? 

Comment: One doubt, why there is a hidden button for each radio button. If they are used to submit a form, you can handle that using single button for form and ref can be passed to that button from  parent and click can be triggered for that ref.

Comment: Actually every option method has its own forms and submits handler and as per the designer's design, there should only one button to trigger the submit button depending on what option method the user selected. 

Comment: Hi Neo Genesis, I have made changes using ref, but Iam not sure whether this is a perfect fix. Check whether your are ok with this fix.

https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-hodgkin-jm84w?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thank you brother this works for me! Thanks for `forwardedRef`. Can you please update your answer so I can mark it. 